# Would adding links between pages help Google index more of our site?

Tags: googlebot, search-engine-indexing, links, google-index

We have a hotel search website. We have identified some concepts that we would like Google to index, for example, we have a landing page for "Boutique Hotels in Chicago, IL", Given number of cities in the U.S., we have more than 100K such pages.

**However, Google is currently indexing our pages at the rate of only ~350 pages per day.** And over 100K pages will take a year to index.

Our website can currently be navigated mostly by typing search queries + destination cities. It's similar to other travel search sites. There are almost no internal links between each landing page. In this case, **is it important to start putting internal links between pages/improve navigation (e.g. breadcrumbs style [city] >> [some query]) and does it help to improve crawling speed?**

Comment: Are you currently relying on sitemaps as the sole means to let Googlebot know about your pages?  If so you should read [The Sitemap Paradox](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/4803/the-sitemap-paradox).

Comment: Hello Stephen - yes only sitemaps contain the urls of the landing pages. I will read it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google needs a source for the links of your pages, so it can index them. There are multiple ways than can make Google index more pages:

- Add a sitemap with most of the pages.
- Include breadcrumbs in your pages.
- Submit the urls using Search Console or via the API.

So the simple answer to the question *Would adding links between pages help Google index more of our site?* is yes.